# Understanding singular homology

Tags: homology-cohomology, simplex

On the [Wikipedia page for singular homology:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_homology)

> Consider first the set of all possible singular n-simplices $\sigma_n(\Delta^n)$ on a topological space X. This set may be used as the basis of a free abelian group, so that each $\sigma_n(\Delta^n)$ is a generator of the group.

This makes sense to me, but I'm not sure how they form a group. What is the group operation? Is there a notion of adding/subtracting simplexes that I don't know about? If so, the wikipedia page also states that the simplices are the *generators* of the group, so what are all the other elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take *formal* linear combinations of the generating simplices. For example,
$$3\sigma + 2\mu$$
is an element of that group, where $\sigma,\mu$ are two $n$-simplices. The group operation is addition, so
$$(3\sigma + 2\mu) + \sigma = 4\sigma + 2\mu$$
and
$$(2\sigma) + (14\mu) = 2\sigma + 14\mu\ .$$

---

In other words, you are taking the $\mathbb Z$-module
$$\bigoplus_{\sigma\ n\text{-simplex}}\mathbb{Z}\sigma = \operatorname{span}_\mathbb{Z}\{\sigma\ n\text{-simplex}\}$$
spanned by all the $n$-simplices and looking at its abelian group structure.

Comment: That makes sense. I've never actually taken a linear algebra class, so I want to try to get some intuition for this - say, on $R^2$, what does it "look like" to multiply a simplex by a scalar, or two add two simpleces?

Comment: @TreFox $\lambda\cdot\sigma$ for $\lambda$ a scalar is just that, the formal multiplication of $\sigma$ by $\lambda$, adding two different simplices is the formal sum of the two, and $\sigma+\sigma = 2\sigma$.

Comment: But if the results of adding simplices are simplices themselves, aren’t they already included in the generators of the group (because the generators are all simplices on the space)?

Comment: @TreFox They are not purely simplices, but formal linear combinations of simplices, much as a vector space is not composed by elements of a basis, but by linear combinations of such elements.

Comment: That makes sense. Is the resulting structure a simplical complex?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a free abelian group, the group operation is *formal* addition i.e. the sum of $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ is just $\sigma_1 + \sigma_2$. The generators of this group are singular $n$-simplices, which means that a generic element looks like a formal sum of these simplifies i.e $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \sigma_i$$ Adding and subtracting simplices is just that, formally adding and subtracting them.
The signs on the simplices correspond to the orientation we take on them, and the addition is formal. You can think of it as a union in the image (it’s usually how it’s drawn) but that isn’t technically true. You can think of multiplying by a scalar as just saying “take $n$ copies of this simplex”.